# float text right and not image

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to the push the images back to the left under the title. Only floating the description text to the right. I can't seem to clear the image floats.

HTML:

```
<div class="title">System Displays</div>
<div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
 <img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x200/000/fff" /> 
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </div>
```

CSS:

```
.title {    
width: 200px;
float: left;
} 

.description{    
width: 200px;
float: right;
} 

.description img {
float: left;
clear: both; 
}
```

The [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/McXHq/) is clearer. I can't insert any extra HTML. Thanks for any advice.

EDIT: And this [[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/McXHq/2/)] is what I visually want to achieve. I'm not sure if `position: relative;` is appropriate though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jsfiddle differs greatly from your example code. Here is the fixed [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/McXHq/1/).

```
.description img {    
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
```

If you need `.description` to have a fixed width, you are going to need another solution. You can't float something outside of its container box.

Here is an example of another method using `absolute` positioning.

```
.description img {
position:absolute;
top:25px; 
left:0;
width:200px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/McXHq/3/)

Here is another method using `relative` positioning:

```
.description img {
    width:200px;
    position:relative;
    left:-220px;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:-100px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/McXHq/5/)

Comment: Thanks, is positioning using css a 'hack' rather than using floats? Also, when you have more than one image they stack rather than going to the left.

Comment: Absolutely not. Just different methods of moving things around on the page. I added another concept you might use that takes advantage of `relative` positioning.

Comment: Thanks, I guess negative values and positioning have a bad connotations. Building of `relative` values this would be ok then http://jsfiddle.net/McXHq/2/